# Add Custom action to GI Mass Actions dropdown

Tags: acumatica

I have extended the Shipments graph and have included 3 new actions.
These 3 new actions are not listed in the Mass Actions dropdown of the Generic Inquiry page:

[image: GI Mass Actions]

I have compared the PXAction<> definition but have not been able to identify an attribute either in the Graph or in the ASPX to enable this option.

Is it possible to add custom actions to that dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

To make it available in the list, make sure you set the PXAction.IsMass flag to true

```cs
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOShipmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            MyAction.IsMass = true;
        }

        public PXAction<SOShipment> MyAction;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Action")]
        public void myAction()
        {
            throw new PXException("My action !");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was incorrect. This is the correct answer. Thanks for helping me out as well Simon!